# Primefaces theme overwrites Bootstrap's classes - Stylesheets order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using `Primefaces 5.0`.

I have a `commandButton` which I want to style with Bootstrap's classes `btn` and `btn-warning`, this is how the code looks like:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-warning pull-right" icon="ui-icon-close"
        value="Delete" action="#{houseProfileView.deleteImage}" update="images">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{img}" target="#{houseProfileView.selectedImage}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

This is how the button looks on hovered state:
[image: btn-on-hover]
As you see, it's not completely filled with the background of `btn-warning`.

And *without the orange border and the semi-filled orange background* is how it looks on the default state.

---

As I've checked the order of inclusion of the stylesheets, I've noticed that Primefaces stylesheet is added automatically to the end, [**this**](http://pastebin.com/BYCqGcJS) is the `head` regarding the stylesheets.
And also, using the element inspection I see that the rules of bootstrap are overwritten by the ones of primefaces.

**I've tried these:**

1. Using facets `middle` and `last` and adding into them this: `<h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap.min.css" library="css"/>` with no luck
2. Including this `<h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap.min.css" library="css"/>` at the end of the `body`.

Comment: Possibly you're encountering https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13093 ?

Comment: @cvrebert Probably, but as I see with the rules at `Element inspection` I can see that every bootstrap rule is overriden by bootstrap, as codeturner below explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css selectors used by primefaces for buttons will override the bootstrap btn and btn-warning selectors due to css precedence rules, regardless of which library is imported first.

(Note that primefaces is doing us a favor by inserting their styles at the end of your header to ensure that your own definitions will be able to override theirs, if you choose to do that.)

Bootstrap was designed with very simple css selectors for flexibility.  This is good.  But to get it to work with primefaces, you'll have to copy the styles out of bootstrap.css that you want into your project, and then modify its css selectors so that they will take precedence over primefaces, such as:

```
.ui-button.btn-warning { ... }
```

This will also allow you to handle the case when primefaces add the 'ui-state-hover' class when hovering over the button.

Not ideal, I know.  Primefaces has a bootstrap theme, but it doesn't appear to match bootstrap completely, so your options are limited.

Comment: Yeah, there's no easy fix.  But this will work with a few hours effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the !important CSS declaration

Comment: I want to integrate a bootstrap class, not my own style, so `!important` isn't of use here.

Comment: Did u put the facets last in the head or in the body ?